# Estimating survival curve with incomplete data

Tags: bayesian, estimation, survival, survey

I am attempting to estimate a (set of) survival/retention curve(s) from survey data. Unfortunately, the data I have is incomplete. I know:

- How long current (alive) subscribers have had the service
- How long ago former (lapsed) subscribers *cancelled* their service

I don't know:

- How long lapsed subscribers had their service before cancelling

If I had the missing piece of data, it would be trivial to align the starting dates for everyone and estimate a retention curve using the normal techniques.

I am hoping there is a clever way to make inferences here.

Comment: Interesting question -- I look forward to reading the answers from those more knowledgeable than me on this one. Is the information in the first two bullet points from company records (i.e. accurate) or from respondent answers (i.e. subject to error)?

Comment: @zbicyclist it is from survey (so subject to error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my Aunt, who is a professor of biostatistics at Duke:

> The first question is "what question are you trying to answer?"  If, as per in a usual survival model, you are trying to understand the median "survival" time of subscription, or the hazard function for dropping the subscription, then alas, no es posible.
>
> The reason is that the most essential piece of information (i.e., how quickly one drops their subscription) is not present in either of the two measures you have.  None of the people that still hold their subscription (regardless of how long that has been) has yet encountered the "event" (unsubscribing) that you are interested in.  They are all censored, in survival analysis terminology.  All of the people who already dropped their subscriptions (regardless of how long ago) provide no information on how long they subscribed, before they dropped.  In survival analysis language, they all have the event, but none have a "time-to-event".